# Transferring images from one iPad to another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have an app which displays an image when I say some word, and the word is from my dictionary which I had exclusively created for the app.

Now I want that image displayed on my friends iPad simultaneously, when it shows on my iPad. Is there any way for that?

Thanks and regards,

Christy

Comment: Pls be more precise and tell what is it that exactly you want?

Comment: i have an app which displays an image when i say some word and the word is from my dictionary which i had exclusively created for the app.now i want that when an image is displayed in my ipad ,then simultaneously that image has to be displayed in my friend's ipad.is there any way for that?-thanks

Comment: You are mixing uo the tags [xcode] and [cocoa-touch]. Xcode is just an IDE (so only questions about how to handle Xcode should be tagged with [xcode]), while the framework is Cocoa Touch.

Comment: please dont hide important informations in comments, but edit your original question

Comment: This also has nothing to do with iPhones, hence I changed that tag (if it wasn't done before). Also updated the question itself. Please be more clear in your questions next time and care for the tags, it saves a lot of time.

Comment: Will both iPads be in the same local network?

Comment: yes both will be in same network

Comment: please edit your question to present this important information in the best place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both iPads are in the same local network, you can use [cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) to run a HTTP-Server on every device and announce the services via Bonjour. Once a new picture is available, that devices connects the server on the other devices and informs it, that new data is available. The second device than will connect the server running on the first device and download the picture.
the advantage of this approach: the protocols you are using are well-know and a lot of additionally tools are available.

But you can also have a similar, more downlevel appoach, where you design your own network protocol. In that case I'd use [Asyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/)

Answer (score 0):

Use synchronize image with both ipad using internet or use APN to notify that image is ready.